# Difference between installing Xfce4 and Xubuntu-desktop?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu.  I like Unity but when I'm doing "heavier" stuff, I like the speed of Xfce.  I know there's other flavours such as Xubuntu that I could install, but I've noticed that other flavours (like Lubuntu) tend to be either washed out or not as stable, so I figured that I'd install Ubuntu and then switch desktops when I need to.  Here's my question:

I've read about installing `xfce4` and `xubuntu-desktop` and I was wondering what the differences were between them?  Benefits? Risks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XFCE is only the desktop environment. xubuntu-desktop, on the other hand is XFCE + additional packages to improve the user experience.

Packages in xubuntu-desktop -

> abiword abiword-common abiword-plugin-grammar abiword-plugin-mathview 
>   apt-offline blueman brltty-x11 catfish desktop-base exo-utils gigolo
>   gmusicbrowser gnome-desktop-data gnome-icon-theme-full
>   gnome-system-tools   gnome-themes-standard gnome-themes-standard-data
>   gnumeric gnumeric-common   gnumeric-doc gtk-theme-config
>   gtk2-engines-pixbuf libabiword-3.0   libchamplain-0.12-0
>   libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0 libdigest-crc-perl libexo-1-0   libexo-common
>   libexo-helpers libgarcon-1-0 libgarcon-common libgdome2-0
>   libgdome2-cpp-smart0c2a libgoffice-0.10-10 libgoffice-0.10-10-common
>   libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgstreamer-perl libgtk2-notify-perl
>   libgtk2-trayicon-perl libgtkmathview0c2a libgtksourceview2.0-0
>   libgtksourceview2.0-common libgtkspell0 libjpeg-progs
>   libjpeg-turbo-progs   libkeybinder0 liblink-grammar4 libloudmouth1-0
>   liboobs-1-5 libotr5 libots0   libsexy2 libtagc0 libthunarx-2-0
>   libtidy-0.99-0 libtumbler-1-0 libvte-common   libvte9 libwv-1.2-4
>   libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4ui-2-0 libxfce4ui-common   libxfce4ui-utils
>   libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfce4util6   libxfcegui4-4
>   libxfconf-0-2 light-locker light-locker-settings   lightdm-gtk-greeter
>   link-grammar-dictionaries-en menulibre mousepad mugshot   orage parole
>   pastebinit pidgin pidgin-data pidgin-libnotify pidgin-otr
>   plymouth-theme-xubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-xubuntu-text
>   python3-pexpect   python3-psutil ristretto shimmer-themes
>   system-tools-backends thunar   thunar-archive-plugin thunar-data
>   thunar-media-tags-plugin thunar-volman   tumbler tumbler-common
>   xbrlapi xchat xchat-common xchat-indicator xfburn   xfce4-appfinder
>   xfce4-cpugraph-plugin xfce4-dict xfce4-indicator-plugin
>   xfce4-mailwatch-plugin xfce4-netload-plugin xfce4-notes
>   xfce4-notes-plugin   xfce4-notifyd xfce4-panel xfce4-places-plugin
>   xfce4-power-manager   xfce4-power-manager-data
>   xfce4-quicklauncher-plugin xfce4-screenshooter   xfce4-session
>   xfce4-settings xfce4-systemload-plugin xfce4-taskmanager
>   xfce4-terminal xfce4-verve-plugin xfce4-volumed xfce4-weather-plugin
>   xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin xfce4-xkb-plugin xfconf xfdesktop4
>   xfdesktop4-data   xfwm4 xscreensaver xscreensaver-data xubuntu-artwork
>   xubuntu-community-wallpapers xubuntu-default-settings xubuntu-desktop 
>   xubuntu-docs xubuntu-icon-theme xubuntu-wallpapers

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! Question, though: would installing the full deal in any way mess up my current desktop?